# Call a local variable outside of its environment

Tags: javascript

I tried to get the value of the `snapAuthor` variable outside of its function this way but the console tells me it did not find it!

```
<b:tag name='script' type='text/javascript'>

function OuterFn(){
var snapAuthor = AuthorsInfo.filter(function(a){

return a.name===&#39;<data:title/>&#39;

})[0];


if(snapAuthor!==undefined){
snapAuthor.provided=true;

<b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
<b:if cond='data:link.name contains &quot;-ad&quot;'>
snapAuthor[&#39;<data:link.name/>&#39;]=&#39;<data:link.target.jsEscaped/>&#39;;
<b:else/>
<b:switch var='data:link.name'>
<b:case value='rank'/>snapAuthor.rank=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
<b:case value='about'/>snapAuthor.about=&#39;<data:link.target.escaped/>&#39;;
<b:default/>snapAuthor.links[&#39;<data:link.name/>&#39;]=&#39;<data:link.target/>&#39;;
</b:switch>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
}

var getSlices = function(){
return snapAuthor;
}
var slice = function(){
snapAuthor++;
}
};

var outerFn = new OuterFn();
console.log(outerFn.getSlices);// undefined
console.log(outerFn.slice);// undefined

</b:tag>
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a variable in JavaScript is the function. So if this variable is defined in a function, you are not able to access to it outside this function. 
You should define the variable elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the variable outside the function OuterFn function as:

```
var snapAuthor;
```

And then in the function just fill the data in it

```
function OuterFn(){
snapAuthor = AuthorsInfo.filter(function(a){
```

This should do the trick.